# Probability Density Function from Random Variable Transformation

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

The problem 2.7 from Casella & Berger asks us to **find the pdf of $Y = X^2$, given $$f_X(x)=\frac{2}{9}(x+1) \quad \text{ for }-1 \le x \le 2$$**

I reasoned and concluded that, assuming $Y=g(X)=X^2$, $g(\cdot)$ is monotonic over $X \in (-1, 0)$ and over $X \in (0, 2)$, given $X$ limits.

My approach is, given partitions on $X$, $A_1=(-1,0)$ and $A_2=(1,2)$, similar to Example 2.1.9, I get the following pdf (essentially applying Theorem 2.1.8):
$$f_y(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^2f_X(g_i^{-1}(y))\Bigg\lvert \frac{d}{dy}g_i^-1(y) \Bigg\rvert ,$$
assuming $g(x) = g_i(x)$ for $x \in A_i$.

I really do not see why I cannot apply Theoreom 2.1.8 given those partitions.

The [solution](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf) gives conditional pdf over intervals $| x | < 1$ and $x > 1$ and I also cannot understand the disjoint results cannot be added together.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is "Theorem 2.1.8"?

Comment: Sorry about that. Theorem 2.1.8 is the one that enables us to get the full pdf of the transformed variable as sums of piecewise transformations. [This question describes it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618174/pdfs-of-piecewise-transformations-why-doesnt-it-apply-in-this-case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=x^2$. Define $Y=g(X)$. For $y>0$ there are two points $x_1=\sqrt{y}$ and $x_2 = -\sqrt{y}$ that satisfy $g(x_1)=g(x_2)=y$. So 
$$ f_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{f_X(x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}  =  \frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})+f_X(-\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}\quad  \forall y > 0 $$
We are given 
$$ f_X(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{2}{9}(x+1) & \mbox{ if $-1\leq x \leq 2$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$
Thus

- $0<y\leq 1 \implies f_X(\sqrt{y})=\frac{2}{9}(\sqrt{y}+1) ,   f_X(-\sqrt{y})=\frac{2}{9}(-\sqrt{y}+1)$.
- $1<y\leq 4 \implies f_X(\sqrt{y})=\frac{2}{9}(\sqrt{y}+1) ,   f_X(-\sqrt{y})=0$.
- $y>4 \implies f_X(\sqrt{y}) = 0 ,  f_X(-\sqrt{y})=0$.

Thus
$$ f_Y(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{2}{9\sqrt{y}} & \mbox{ if $0<y\leq 1$} \\
\frac{\sqrt{y} + 1}{9\sqrt{y}} & \mbox{ if $1<y\leq 4$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else}\end{array}\right. $$
You can verify that 
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{2}{9\sqrt{y}} dy + \int_1^4\frac{\sqrt{y}+1}{9\sqrt{y}} dy = 1$$

Comment: That is very useful, @michael, thank you a lot. Quick question, in the [solution](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf), it is claimed that the partitions are A1=(-1, 1) and A2=(1,2). Do you think it is maybe a typo?